# Beautiful way to resolve an object with nested promises?

Tags: javascript, express, promise, loopbackjs, bluebird

While building custom endpoints I often need to resolve a complex object containing promises.

For illustration, take this example:

Given known user's *id*, *employeeId* and *memberGroupsIds* (an array):

```
var loginResponse = {
    userprofile : getProfile(id)
    companyInfo : {
        company : getCompany(employeeId)
        companyRelations : getPriviligedInfo(employeeId)
    }
    groups : getGroups(memberGroupsIds)
}
```

This logic works for synchronous functions that just return their values. But with functions that return promises I have to manually push all of them into an array to ensure they are resolved before using the final object.

I find the above code very easy to understand, and I'm looking for a signature that gives some of that, while still ensuring that the promises are resolved before sending a final object to the client.

*The problem is not making it work, but making it beautiful and easy to read.*

The best answer would ensure that the values are returned to the expected keys in the object and that all the promises are resolved in parallel, while maintaining a structure that is somewhat compatible with that of synchronous functions.

Or, if I'm missing the point and looking at this all wrong, how should I be looking at it?

Comment: `var loginResponse = Promise.all([getProfile(Id), getCompany(EmployeeId), getPriviligedInfo(EmployeeId), getGroups(MemberGroupsIds)]).then(([userprofile, company, companyRelations, groups]) => ({ userprofile, companyInfo: { company, companyRelations }, groups}));` - of course, you can't just use `loginResponse` as the value, because it's a promise ... so, use would be `loginResponse.then(obj => { ... do things here ... });`

Comment: Yes, that works, but doesn't really make it obvious how the return object is structured / comes to be or easy to add new children as the requirements expand (imaging this being used for a object 10 times the size/complexity of the example)

Comment: obviously in a single line like that it's not pretty - do you want **working** code or **pretty** code - guess you could use async/await to make it pretty

Comment: I want pretty code :) 
As I said, the problem is not making it work, but making it have a syntax somewhat comparable to that of the example object

Comment: Can't believe that nobody suggested it. IMO, the real way to go here is to return all the data you need using a single call to the server rather than having to wait for 4 separate calls to complete. Nobody said beautiful code is smart code.

Comment: This is already serverside and if you are thinking DB server, this could be returning from any number of different servers, APIs or polymorphic relations where you don't know the instance model type before it is loaded. Obviously the target is to get the promises to run in parallel, so I'm not sure if the criticism is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the helper function below. It takes an object and returns a promise that resolves when all nested promises have been resolved. The returned promise will provide as value the same object, which will have mutated with all its embedded promises replaced by their corresponding values.

```
function promiseRecursive(obj) {
    const getPromises = obj =>
        Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, key) =>
            Object(obj[key]) !== obj[key]
                ? acc
                : acc.concat(
                    typeof obj[key].then === "function"
                        ? [[obj, key]]
                        : getPromises(obj[key])
                  )
        , []);
    const all = getPromises(obj);
    return Promise.all(all.map(([obj, key]) => obj[key])).then( responses =>
        (all.forEach( ([obj, key], i) => obj[key] = responses[i]), obj) 
    );
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
var loginResponsePromise = promiseRecursive({
    userprofile : getProfile(10),
    companyInfo : {
        company : getCompany(101),
        companyRelations : getPriviligedInfo(101)
    },
    groups : getGroups([5])
});
```

```js
function promiseRecursive(obj) {
    const getPromises = obj =>
        Object.keys(obj).reduce( (acc, key) =>
            Object(obj[key]) !== obj[key] ? acc
                : acc.concat(typeof obj[key].then === "function" ? [[obj, key]] 
                : getPromises(obj[key]))
        , []);
    const all = getPromises(obj);
    return Promise.all(all.map(([obj, key]) => obj[key])).then( responses =>
        (all.forEach( ([obj, key], i) => obj[key] = responses[i]), obj) 
    );
}

// Example promise-returning functions
const wait = ms => new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms) ),
    getProfile = id => wait(100).then(_ => ({userName: 'user' + id,id})),
    getCompany = employeeId => wait(200).then(_ => ({employeeName: 'employee' + employeeId, employeeId})),
    getPriviligedInfo = employeeId => wait(500).then(_ => ({privs: 'privInfo' + employeeId, employeeId})),
    getGroups = memberGroupsIds => wait(400).then(_ => ({groups: ['group' + memberGroupsIds[0]],memberGroupsIds}));

// Sample input passed to `promiseRecursive` function
const loginResponsePromise = promiseRecursive({
    userprofile : getProfile(10),
    companyInfo : {
        company : getCompany(101),
        companyRelations : getPriviligedInfo(101)
    },
    groups : getGroups([5])
});

// Display the resolved object
loginResponsePromise.then( o => console.log(o) );
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This looks promising (no pun intended). I'll try it out tomorrow, but defo a strong candidate for an accepted solution (syntax of the promiseRecursive helper is a little confusing to me, but I'll get it, and should also be possible to make it go deeper by making it recursive). The loginResponse returns a promise of the passed object resolved, so not really the response but the promise of the response (just a naming thing). I would probably implement as a global helper and do something like `promiseRecursive({loginObj}).then(o=>loginResponse = o)` unless there is a reason not to do it this way?

Comment: Indeed, the function returns a promise, so you need to apply `then` on it to get the resolved object (see also the snippet). Note that any solution will have to hand you the resolved object in an asynchronous way. It is not possible to create a function that will `return` the result in a *synchronous* way, as obviously the internal promises only give you their final values in an asynchronous way. You speak of *making it recursive*: it is recursive. Not sure what else you mean?

Comment: Thanks @trincot Yeah. I got the "has to return asynchronously", just reiterating to help my own understanding :) Hmm.. I think I see the recursive now (I never really use ternary operations and ES6 missing parentheses it still a bit unusual to me). Nifty little piece of code there!

Comment: I indented the ternary operator a bit more clearly in the text now, and provided a better name for the result variable so it is clear it is a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I usually solve this kind of scenarios with Bluebird's `join` http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html :

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

return Promise.join(
    getProfile(id),
    getCompany(employeeId),
    getPrivilegedInfo(employeeId),
    getGroups(memberGroupsIds),
    (userProfile, company, companyRelations, groups) => {
        return {
            userProfile: userProfile,
            companyInfo: {
                company: company,
                companyRelations: companyRelations
            },
            groups: groups
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using new ES6 features I would write something like this:

```
Promise.all([
    getProfile(id),
    getCompany(employeeId),
    getPriviligedInfo(employeeId),
    getGroups(memberGroupsIds)
])
.then(response => {

    const [ userprofile, company, companyRelations, groups ] = response

    const loginResponse = {
      userprofile,
      companyInfo : {
        company,
        companyRelations
      },
      groups
    }
})
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Maybe the interesting part is that `Promise.all()` keep the input arguments order not depending on which resolves first. So in next step, using [Destructuring Array assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), the code looks like synchronous.